# Fatal error: Call to undefined function Frisbee\Helpers\password_hash()

Tags: php, twig, slim

So I've been following along with the phpacademy [Authentication System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frfHPD9NFF4&index=15&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGKUvioJly40RJZchSG2-34&spfreload=1) tutorials and I've managed to get up to video 15 in the series but in the latest video I had tot upload the site onto a web server that wasn't localised.

However, in doing so my hashing function no longer works and I receive the error mentioned above.

```
<?php
namespace Frisbee\Helpers;
class Hash {
   protected $config;

   public function __construct($config){
      $this->config = $config;
   }

   public function password($password){
      return password_hash($password, $this->config->get('app.hash.algo'),
          ['cost' => $this->config->get('app.hash.cost')]
      );
   }

   public function passwordCheck($password, $hash){
       return password_verify($password, $hash);
   }
}
```

Researching online I've found that it could be something to do with PHP versions but I can't see on my CPanel which PHP version I'm using.

Comment: Where is the function password_hash defined? I do not see any class includes. Is passwordCheck function working? (assuming password_verify is in the same file as password_hash)

Comment: are you on v5.5.0+ That's when password_hash() was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

[password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) where added in php 5.5 so that is probably what you are missing. You can rectify this by using ircmaxells [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) library that defines the same functions but works on older versions of PHP.

Comment: Oh cool thanks, I'll probably have to look into this before I switch to another web host! :P

Answer (score 0):

The password() and password_verify() functions are not installed on all versions of PHP. So it is most likely that your server is not running the latest version of PHP. You can check the PHP version on your server either via phpinfo() or phpversion().

"Researching online I've found that it could be something to do with PHP versions but I can't see on my CPanel which PHP version I'm using."

Just create a new php file and echo out phpversion()

```
echo phpversion();
```

Comment: Interesting... so firstly, thanks for the code. After adding it to my index.php it appears my server is running PHP Version '5.4.39' which is stupid. I can't even configure it which is a joke. Either way, thanks again! :P

Comment: There you go. As @Orangepill stated this wasn't introduced until 5.5 so that's why it's not working. You don't have to switch hosts necessarily, instead ask them to upgrade. If nobody ever asks them to update, they will feel like they won't have to. And if they decline to upgrade and then you leave, they just lost a customer. Good luck!

Comment: Oh okay, that's actually good to know. I did send them an email asking what version they were running and why I couldn't configure the PHP version myself under 'PHP Configuration' but they haven't replied yet, but hopefully they will soon! :D